# Performing a WHERE - IN query in CouchDB

Tags: sql, database, couchdb, where-in

I would like to query for a list of particular documents with one call to CouchDB.

With SQL I would do something like

```
SELECT *
FROM database.table
WHERE database.table.id
IN (2,4,56);
```

What is a recipe for doing this in CouchDB by either `_id` or another field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use views `keys` [query parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options) to get records with keys in specified set.

```
function(doc){
    emit(doc.table.id, null);
}
```

And then

```
GET /db/_design/ddoc_name/_view/by_table_id?keys=[2,4,56]
```

To retrieve document content in same time just add `include_docs=True` query parameter to your request.

*UPD*: Probably, you might be interested to retrieve documents by this reference ids (2,4,56). By default CouchDB views "maps" emitted keys with documents they belongs to. To tweak this behaviour you could use [linked documents](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Linked_documents) trick:

```
function(doc){
    emit(doc.table.id, {'_id': doc.table.id});
}
```

And now request

```
GET /db/_design/ddoc_name/_view/by_table_id?keys=[2,4,56]&include_docs=True
```

will return rows with `id` field that points to document that holds `2`,`4` and `56` keys and `doc` one that contains referenced document content.

Comment: using the `keys` parameter in the url clarifies things for me greatly. I just had an Aha! moment.  thanks (ps. spelling mistake on 'linked documents' link)

Answer (score 3):

In CouchDB Bulk document APi is used for this:

```
curl -d '{"keys":["2","4", "56"]}' -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/foo/_all_docs?include_docs=true
```

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API

Comment: Also, do you know if the Bulk document API has any significant performance difference to a writing a `view` that emits `emit(doc._id, doc)` OR `emit(doc._id, doc._id)` with `?include_docs=true`

Comment: Yes, that works for IDs, that's correct. As far as I know _all_docs is also a view so there should be no difference in performance.