# Query CouchDB with multiple keys for multiple properties

Tags: rest, key, view, couchdb

I'm using couch db to store subscription documents. While performing queries, I want to be able to query on multiple properties and also use an "IN" clause. For example, I have a `subscriptionStatus` property which can have multiple values (Active, Failed, In_Progress etc.) and subscriptions also have a `customerID`.

How can I create a query for all subscriptions where customerID = "JD212S" AND subscriptionStatus IN ["Active", "In_Progress"]

Essentially show me active and in progress subscriptions for a particular customer.
I looked at combinations of views, multiple keys etc but I was not able to do this (or I've misunderstood the docs).

I've had a look at a number of Stack Overflow Q/A and CouchDB docs for this but seem to find options only for a single property at a time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performing a WHERE - IN query in CouchDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763430/performing-a-where-in-query-in-couchdb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it does look list a duplicate, but in your context you would create a view return multiple keys then when executing that view, like the link here states, pass in your multi-key options

```
// view foo/bar
var view = function(doc) {
   doc.emit([doc.customerId, doc.subscriptionStatus]);
}

db.view('foo/bar', { keys: [['JD212S','Active'], 
['JD212S','In_Progress']], include_docs: true });
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I will try this. My confusion was I didn't realize I could specify the keys like so and was working out how to put them all in a single array. So essentially, each entry in the keys array is a complex key (JSON Array) in itself. Got it!
It does mean though, for e.g. if I had many with many values, I'd be creating all combinations of complex key :)
Anyways, thanks a lot for the answer, this is what I was looking for.